# How to edit the list of items in the "Startup Projects" Combo-Box in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

The Standard Toolbar in Visual Studio has 3 combo-boxes: One for the configurations, one for the platforms and one for the "Startup Projects". In my solution the "Startup Projects" combox has 3 items: One for my "main" project .exe, one for a command line tool .exe and a third one for a project doesn't even have any code. I have another project in that solution, that creates an .exe.

Now, from that combo, i would like to remove the project that does not have any code in it and i would like to add the one for the .exe that is not in it. When i right click on the .exe project, i can chooses "Set as Standard project" and the project is added to the comboboy and made current. However, soon as is make another project the Startup one it gets removed from the combo.

I would like to add it permanently. Any suggestions how i can archive this?